# unable to display multiselect picklist values in vf page

Tags: visualforce

[image]I am unable to display multiselect picklist values using bootstrap library.Can anyone check wht wrong i am doing.

Below is the class and vf page -

Class -

```
public class testcon {
    public string check {get;set;}
     public Product2 changer{get;set;}
      public testcon(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
    this.changer = (Product2)controller.getRecord();
  }

     public List<selectOption> getPax() {
    List<selectOption> options = new List<selectOption>();
    String fullName;
    for (Product2 p : [SELECT Id,Name  from Product2 ]) {
      fullName = p.Name; 
      options.add(new selectOption(fullName, fullName));
     }
     return options;
  }

}
```

Vf page -

```
<apex:page standardstylesheets="false"  showHeader="true" extensions="testcon" standardController="Product2">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" type="text/css"/>

  <meta charset="utf-8"/>

</head>
<apex:form>

<select id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple" >

    <apex:repeat value="{!changer.Name}" var="stage">  
                <option value="{!pax}">{!pax}</option>  
            </apex:repeat>  
</select>



<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#example-multiple-selected').multiselect();
</script>

</apex:form>
</html>
</apex:page>
```

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!changer.Name}" var="stage">
```

to:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!pax}" var="stage">
```

your repeat should iterate on the list of product names.

*edit*:

**change in page**

```
<select id="example-multiple-selected" multiple="multiple" >
    <apex:repeat value="{!pax}" var="stage">  
        <option value="{!stage.value}">{!stage.label}</option>  
    </apex:repeat>  
</select>
```

**Use a wrapper in controller:**

```
public class Multiselect_BS {
    public string check { get;set; }
    public Product2 changer{ get;set; }
    public Multiselect_BS(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        this.changer = (Product2)controller.getRecord();
    }
    public List<ProductWrapper> getPax() {
        List<ProductWrapper> options = new List<ProductWrapper>();
        for (Product2 p : [SELECT Id,Name  from Product2 ]) {
            options.add(new ProductWrapper(p.Id, p.Name));
        }
        return options;
    }

    // using wrapper
    public class ProductWrapper {
        public String value { get; set; }
        public String label { get; set; }
        public ProductWrapper(String value, String label) {
            this.value = value;
            this.label = label;
        }
    }
}
```

Adding screenshot:
[image]

Comment: Hi rahui..its coming like above..

Comment: updated the post, you should wrapper list instead of select options.

Comment: Thanks rahul for the save.. I there any way to implement slds on this vage..

Comment: I am new to SLDS :)

Comment: ok .. last question if u dont mind.. can we remove the checkbox and only show a tick..is it possible

Comment: It has something to do with CSS, try playing with it :)

Watch this question for SLDS - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143892/is-it-possible-to-replicate-slds-multiselect-list-using-real-time-data-from-cust